# Community Navigation Menu Item Not Present for "Guest Users"

Tags: community, navigation-menu

I have a Salesforce Community, and I am attempting to display specific menu-items to unauthenticated "Guest Users".

I have marked the Navigation Item (which points to a Community Page) to "Publically Available"

I then publish the Community, and open the URL in an anonymous browser - and only the "Home" menu item is displayed?

How do I conditionally render specific menu items to un-authenticated/Guest users?

[image]

Comment: Been a while I had worked with communities, if I remember correctly, we can map the navigation to profile with audience feature?

Comment: According to [official SF documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_setup_nav_menu.htm&type=5), marking a navigation menu item as "Publicly Available" should expose it to the guest users. May be you are seeing this problem owing to browser cache? or missed out to publish the changes?

Comment: Thanks all I do believe there is additional logic, with different menus' being displayed based on the audience that I didn't match up the naming convention

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Didn't really get what you meant by "didn't match up the naming convention"?

Comment: So the developers had created multiple navigation menu's with different names (the names of these menus' did not match the expected menu items)

Comment: Sounds like this was a configuration issue, already solved? Please post an answer and accept it to close this question off.